# Integrating Chili publish into Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, iframe

**What I have tried:**

I followed the [Reverse Proxy on Apache](http://docs.chili-publish.com/display/CPD4/Reverse+Proxy+on+Apache).  Then I created a simple html page with an iframe and followed the [Javascript integration](http://docs.chili-publish.com/display/CPD4/Getting+started+with+your+JavaScript+integration).  I was able to extract the variables from the iframe.

**My issues:**

I created another Reverse Proxy and integrated the html page into a Symfony project.  But I am not able to extract the variables from the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was that I had Symfony on a sub-domain and Chili on another sub-domain.